# Input field with validation crashes when typing fast in Angular 2

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I have a form in Angular 2 with a simple validation using Validators.

### The html template

```
<form role="form" #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()" novalidate [ngFormModel]="form">
    <div class="form-group  list-element">
        <label for="name">name*</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ngControl="name"
               #name="ngForm" placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]=user.name >
    </div>
</form>
```

### The ControlGroup for the validation

```
ngOnInit() {    
    this.form = new ControlGroup({
      name: new Control('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("(([a-zA-Z ]|[0-9])+)*"),
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(80)
      ]))
    });
  }
```

When I type fast (random) characters in the input field (e.g `#1KZBZKBjkndedjk@@@kjbzdzdékj!`) the application crashes. This does not happen always so I have not really noticed a pattern.

This is the place where the crash happens, so I think the crash has something to do with the pattern. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7822 and will probably be fixed when this pull request lands https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7421

Answer (score 1):

**First of all this is not related to AngularJS.**

This happens because your pattern is wrong I don't know what pattern you need but for example if you need to validate email then use this pattern
& Just Check for your pattern nothing else.

your code....

Validators.pattern("^[_a-z0-9]+(.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$"),

your code ends...

That it!